# undefined method `embed' (NoMethodError) occurs randomly executing calabash steps

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, calabash

I'm trying to write some tests for an iOS app in Calabash and I've noticed that occasionally a test will fail at random with the error:

> undefined method `embed' for # (NoMethodError)

There are some things that appear to influence this: The speed of the computer and the stability of the network seem to positively influence the reliability of test execution and make it less likely to occur. Also adding wait steps between some of the failing steps seems to make them work more reliably, but the waiting time seems to matter. A waiting time that's too long still causes test failure. Can anyone clue me in as to what might be going on here and what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in Calabash 0.19.0.  It will be fixed in Calabash 0.19.1.

Until 0.19.1 is released, you can do the following:

```
# In your Gemfile
gem "calabash-cucumber", :github => "calabash/calabash-ios", :branch => "develop"

# Run with bundle exec
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec cucumber
```

Be sure to use `bundle exec` with every ruby command (`cucucmber`, `calabash-ios console`, etc.).

[0.19.0: undefined method `embed` in Calabash::Cucumber.map](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1083)

Comment: Hmm, looks like it doesn't know what develop is: "[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `develop' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue."

Comment: Missing quotes around develop.